# How to disable the message notifications of skype on mac?

Tags: notifications

It is annoying that every time a message arrives, a notification pop up in the right corner of the screen, untill you click the close button. How can I disable this?

I found that a software named `growl` may help, but it is not a free solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Prefs > Notifications

Set alert style to None, or Banner, which will disappear after a few seconds.

[image]